# Avoid user login for facebook feed dialog using FB - JS SDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, fb-graph

I have a Rails 3.2 app that uses `omniauth` gem to authenticate users via Facebook. Once the user is authenticated, i save his FB `user_id` and `access_token` that is generated.

I used `fb_graph` gem to allow users post directly to their friends wall via our app. But recently FB has removed the support of posting to friends wall using their `Graph API`. This has broken my feature of posting to friends wall using fb_graph gem.

Their documentation says we can post to friends wall via `Feed Dialog`. Following is the code I wrote for feed dialog:

```
<p><a onclick="launchFeedDialog(); return false">Testing the Feed Dialog</a></p>
<script>
function launchFeedDialog() {

// calling the API ...
var obj = {
  method: 'feed',
  to: 'RECIPIENT NAME', // Can specify recipient here
  link: 'http://example.com',
  name: 'Test post',
  description: 'Test description'
};

  FB.ui(obj);
}
</script>
```

When I click on the link, it opens FB dialog asks user to login. I need to avoid this as I have already authenticated the user via FB and have his access token. On clicking the link it should ask user to type message and not ask for user credentials.

How can I do this?

Thanks.